# Showing that if $M,s \vDash \exists x \varphi$ then $N,s \vDash \exists x \varphi$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory, quantifiers

Let's say $M$ and $N$ are structures and $s$ is a variable assignment for $M$. Let's also say that $M$ is a substructure of $N$. If $\varphi$ is a formula then I need to prove that if $M,s \vDash \exists x\varphi$ then $N,s \vDash \exists x \varphi$. I can appeal to the fact that $M,s \vDash \varphi$ iff $N,s \vDash \varphi$. $\varphi$ also needs to be quantifier free in order to use this fact. To start off, I know that if $M,s \vDash \exists x \varphi$ then there exists some $x$-variant $s'$ of $s$ such that $M,s' \vDash \varphi$. From there I can use the above fact to say that if $M,s' \vDash \varphi$ then $N,s' \vDash \varphi$.

I'm confused where to go from here. I need to say that $N,s \vDash \exists x \varphi$ but I'm not sure how to get there from $N,s' \vDash \varphi$.

Comment: Do you mean "$M$ is an **elementary** substructure of $N$?" Otherwise the statement is false ...

Comment: I don't know what that is. I've only learned about substructures. I know that φ cannot have any quantifiers or else I couldn't use the iff statement for M, s' to N, s'.

Comment: Trivially $M \subseteq N$ (in terms of *domains*, i.e. if $x \in M$ then $x \in N$). Thus, if $M,s \vDash \exists x \varphi$, this means that there is an $x$-variant of $s$ (call it $s'$) such that $M,s' \vDash \varphi$. But the $x$-variant is "varied" in $M$, i.e. it assigns a suitable element $d$ of $M$ to $x$. That element $d \in N$ also, and thus $s'$ is also an $x$-variant of $s$ in $N$ and thus $N,s' \vDash \varphi$.

Comment: @JoshSusa You should probably mention that $\varphi$ is quantifier-free in the question ...